# Why does this css class have 3 different filter settings?

Tags: css

Are these for cross browser reasons?

Hoping someone can explain them to me:

```
opacity:.50;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter:alpha(opacity=50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for cross-browser compatibility.  Take a look over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp) and [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/filters/alpha.shtml) for an  explanation.

This is for IE:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter:alpha(opacity=50)
```

This will work in pretty much everything else:

```
opacity:.50;
```

Answer (score 0):

Different companies using their own implementation in their browser. [CSS3 officially recognizes the 'opacity' property.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox, IE, other browsers require different CSS entries to render alpha blending.